# Link de la imágen en AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, upload

Cómo hacer para que en el Javascript me devuelva el link de dónde se subió la imagen. Funciona bien ya que sube las imágenes, quería saber cómo puedo hacer para que además me devuelta el link.

script.js

```
var file_data = $('#file').prop('files')[0];
        var form_data = new FormData();
        form_data.append('file', file_data);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'upload.php', 
            dataType: 'text', 
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: form_data,
            type: 'post',
            success: function (response) {
                alert('Agrego imagen');

            },
            error: function (response) {

            }
        });
```

upload.php

```
if (isset($_FILES['file']['name'])) {
    if (0 < $_FILES['file']['error']) {
        echo 'Error during file upload' . $_FILES['file']['error'];
    } else {
        if (file_exists('uploads/' . $_FILES['file']['name'])) {
            echo 'File already exists : uploads/' . $_FILES['file']['name'];
        } else {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/' . $_FILES['file']['name']);
            echo 'File successfully uploaded : uploads/' . $_FILES['file']['name'];
            var direc = $_FILES['file']['name'];
            json_encode($direc);
        }
    }
} else {
    echo 'Please choose a file';
}
```

Formulario

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label for="vendedor">Comprobante</label>
                <input type="file" id="file" placeholder="" class="form-control"/>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="addRecord()" id="agregar">Añadir</button>
```

Comment: Añade el código HTML de tu formulario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el archivo *script.js*, en `success`, agregas `alert(response);` y te mostrará el contenido que devuelvas de *upload.php*

Por otro lado,  para hacer tests es mejor usar `console.log()` y chequear en la consola de la terminal.

Tu ***script.js*** quedaría:

```
var file_data = $('#file').prop('files')[0];
        var form_data = new FormData();
        form_data.append('file', file_data);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'upload.php', 
            dataType: 'text', 
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: form_data,
            type: 'post',
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response); // new line

            },
            error: function (response) {

            }
        });
```

y en archivo ***upload.php***:

```
if (isset($_FILES['file']['name'])) {
    if (0 < $_FILES['file']['error']) {
        $response = 'Error during file upload' . $_FILES['file']['error'];
    } else {
        if (file_exists('uploads/' . $_FILES['file']['name'])) {
            $response = 'File already exists : uploads/' . $_FILES['file']['name'];
        } else {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/' . $_FILES['file']['name']);
            $response = 'File successfully uploaded : uploads/' . $_FILES['file']['name'];

        }
    }
} else {
    $response = 'Please choose a file';
    }
echo $response; //return any message
```